# Google realtime API OBJECT_CHANGED event fired by (almost) anything happening?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

Take a custom realtime object "MyObject" one property of which is an IndexReference referring to a CollaborativeList "MyList". "MyObject" also has a collaborative field property "MyProps" into which I put a json string.

In order to detect changes to "MyProps" I tried the following:

```
MyObject.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.OBJECT_CHANGED, dealWithChanges);
```

However, when I make any change to an object in "MyList", which shouldn't affect the IndexReference in any way, the OBJECT_CHANGED event is fired on "MyObject"

Is this by design? It makes the OBJECT_CHANGED event useless, effectively a "something has changed somewhere" event, but without it there appears no way to detect a change to "MyProps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object changed events bubble, so you can listen higher up the tree for anything that is happening lower.

To listen only for changes on collaborative fields within the particular custom object, you want a [ValueChangedEvent](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.ValueChangedEvent)

Comment: I'm still wondering the designed purpose of OBJECT_CHANGED. Is it a sort-of side-effect event, a "we may as well raise this as all events come through here anyway" thing..?

Comment: ObjectChanged can be useful in various scenarios where you want to take more general action in response to anything changes, rather than have specific logic for each things changing.  Say you have a list of collab objects.. Some UI frameworks make it easy to just say "redraw all" if something changes, rather than updating a specific item.  So you add an ObjectChangedListener on the list, find out if anything within the list changes, and just say "redraw all".

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense.